# Django models with external DBs

Tags: python, django

I have a typical Django project with one primary database where I keep all the data I need.

Suppose there is another DB somewhere with some additional information. That DB isn't directly related to my Django project so let's assume I do not even have a control under it.

The problem is that I do ont know if I need to create and maintain a model for this external DB so I could use Django's ORM. Or maybe the best solution is to use raw SQL to fetch data from external DB and then use this ifo to filter data from primary DB using ORM, or directly in views.

The solution with creating a model seems to be quite ok but the fact that DB isn't a part of my project means I am not aware of possible schema changes and looks like it's a bad practice then.

So in the end if I have some external resources like DBs that are not related to but needed for my project should I:

- Try to create django models for them
- Use raw SQL to get info from external DB and then use it for filtering data from the primary DB with ORM as well as using data directly in views if needed
- Use raw SQL both for a primary and an external DB where they intersect in app's logic

Comment: Several questions:

- Is there an API you could use to access the data you need? If yes, that could be a viable solution to retrieve what you need
- Do you expect data in this database to change often, and do you need to be up to date with those changes? If not, you could just build your own database with a dump of the data you're interested in, and put it in a DjangoModel

Comment: Actually it's mine external application. But I decided to ask a broader question.
Dump is not a solution. Data changes frequently. For example there are two billing panels and you have one METAbilling which gathers data from them. For example these two billing are whmcs and awbs. I have no idea how are they going to change the DB schema.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to use [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) for the external database. It can use [reflection](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/reflection.html) to generate the SQLAlchemy-equivalent of django models during runtime.

It still won't be without issues. If your code depends on a certain column, it would still break if that column is removed or changed in an incompatible way. However, it will add a bit more flexibility to your database interactions, e.g. a Django model would definitely break if an `int` column is changed to a `varchar` column, but using database reflection, it will only break if your code depends on the fact that it is an `int`. If you simply display the data or something, it will remain fully functional. However, there is always a chance that a change doesn't break the system, but causes unexpected behaviour.

If, like Benjamin said, the external system has an API, that would be the preferred choice.

Comment: Actually trying to use this approach I faced the problem - where and how should I integrate SQLAlchemy into my views, forms, etc?
The naive approach was to add the whole connecting DB logging and data fetching in get_queryset which I am not really satisfied with. What with the forms then?
Please if possible provide a short example.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to read about inspectdb and database routers. It's possible to use the django ORM to manipulate a external DB.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/django-admin/#inspectdb

Comment: I am aware of these tools and need some experience based advice. As I understand actually you are saying that I should "Try to create django models for them". So every time schema changes a little bit I have to rewrite my models.

Answer (score 0):

I would create the minimal django models on the external databases => those that interact with your code:

Several outcomes to this

1. If parts of the database you're not interested in change, it won't have an impact on your app.
2. If the external models your using change, you probably want to be aware of that as quickly as possible (your app is likely to break in that case too).
3. All the relational databases queries in your code are handled by the same ORM.